# Jscrollpane ajax wont load in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I am loading a custom scroll panel in to jScrollpane using their AJAX loading script, it works in everything except IE, any ideas on what to do, no errors show up.

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../../JS/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script> 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../../JS/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script> 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../../JS/projpagecode.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../../JS/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script> 
     <script type="application/javascript">

     ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     ////////// CODE CREATE CUSTOM SCROLL BAR    ////////////////
     ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $(function()
        {
            var api = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane(
                {
                    showArrows:false,
                    maintainPosition: false,
                    autoReinitialise: true
                }
            ).data('jsp');
            $('#moreprojects').bind(
                'click',
                function()
                {
                    api.getContentPane().load(
                        'blank.html',//
                        function()
                        {
                            api.reinitialise();
                        }
                    );
                    return false;
                }
            );
        });







    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you viewing over http or does your test URL start with "file://"? I believe that Ajax may only work for "http://" URLs in IE...

Comment: Then I can't see anything wrong with the code. Does blank.html exist? Can you provide a URL demonstrating the problem?